# AWS Cloud Watch - Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid

Tags: aws-lambda, cron, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to setup a Cloudwatch Scheduled Event and my cron expression seems to be invalid and I can't figure out why.

Example expression in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html):

```
cron(15 12 * * ? *) - Run at 12:15 pm (UTC) every day
```

Another example:

```
cron(0 18 ? * MON-FRI *) - Run at 6:00 pm (UTC) every Monday through Friday
```

Now, I want it to run everyday at 18 PM UTC so it seems like this would be what I want.

```
cron(0 18 * * ? *)
```

but I am getting

```
Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid
```

Why is it not valid?

Comment: Are you using the web console?

Comment: Yes, I am using web console.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is misleading. I was thinking for the whole time that you need to type cron(.....) but it turns out you just need to time the expression itself, without cron.

```
0 18 * * ? *
```